# C# memory managment value type inside list

Tags: c#, generics, memory-management

Imagine i've got a method which returns List of value types:

```
static List<SomeValueType> AllocateList()
{
    List<SomeValueType> lst = new List<SomeValueType>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        lst.Add(new SomeValueType("....", "..."));
    }
    return lst;
}
```

I've some misunderstanding. Once we call this method, it will return ref to list of value types, and methods stack frame will be destroyed. But what about `SomeValueType` items. Will it be copied to caller method's stack frame, or boxed, or smth else?

If list items are copied to the heap, what will be the difference between boxing and copying value type to list storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `List<T>` is a reference type. Since it is the encapsulating object, `SomeValueType` will be allocated on the *heap*, not the *stack*. More precisely, after the allocation of `SomeValueType` on the *stack*, it will be lifted to the underlying storage of the `List<T>`, which is on the heap. Thus, there will be no need for stack frame copying or the likes, and there will also be no need for boxing.

Value Types are stack allocated as an implementation detail, they *can be* allocated on the heap without any need for boxing, same way an `int[]` is allocated on the heap.

Comment: In this way, what is the difference between boxing and copying to a list storage?

Comment: @xalz Copying doesn't require an additional object to be allocated on the heap to encapsulate the value type, it is copied as is to the heap.

Answer (score 2):

`SomeValueType` elements will be copied, by value, into the storage inside the `List<SomeValueType>` object. List implementation has a generic array of items inside; this is where `SomeValueType` are stored.

The list itself is a reference type, so `lst` would be returned by reference.

When the caller accesses the list, say, like this:

```
SomeValueType item5 = allocatedList[5];
```

then the value from list's index 5 would be copied into caller's stack frame.